# Is String type a class or a struct? Or something else?

Tags: swift

```
class MyString: String {}
```

gives an error:

> Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'String'`.

So looks like `String` is not a class. But why it can be used in context where `AnyObject` is expected? I though `AnyObject` is for class type only, while `Any` could be a class or non-class type.

Comment: all build-in types are struct/enum. you can't subclass from them.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you command+click `String` in Xcode

```
struct String {
    init()
}
```

So `String` is a `struct`.

You can't subclass from `struct` as the error message said:

> error: Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'String'

However, you can implicitly convert it to `NSString` (which is subtype of `AnyObject`) *only if* you have imported `Foundation` directly or indirectly.

From REPL

```
  1> var str = "This is Swift String" 
str: String = "This is Swift String"
  2> var anyObj : AnyObject = str 
.../expr.oXbYls.swift:2:26: error: type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
var anyObj : AnyObject = str
                         ^
```

---

```
  1> import Foundation // <---- always imported in any useful application
  2> var str = "This is Swift String" 
str: String = "This is Swift String"
  3> var anyObj : AnyObject = str 
anyObj: _NSContiguousString = "This is Swift String" // it is not Swift string anymore
  4>
```

---

But try to avoid to subclass `String` or `NSString` unless you absolute have to. You can read more at [NSString Subclassing Notes](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring).

Use extension to add new method to `String`

```
extension String {
    func print() {
        println(self);
    }
}

"test".print()
```

Use delegation pattern if you want to have more control over it

```
struct MyString {
    let str : String = ""

    func print() {
        println(str)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's right about Struct/Class. Can you tell me why we should never subclass the NSString class ? I'm failing to implement
<!-- language: lang-js -->public override convenience init(string aString: NSString)
It could be a bad idea, but is this not possible at all ?

Comment: @tontonCD well, you could subclass if you have to, but read the Subclassing Notes section first: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring

Comment: @tontonCD What task are you trying to achieve by subclassing? I can almost certainly guarantee there's a better approach.

Comment: sorry for delai, I worked on the redaction of a course, I preferred to give up with the idea. What I found is that override the NSString class require to override some functions, some of the NSString class are defined from Objective-C and translated to Swift using some set of keywords, and the specs say that in this case it's impossible to do. No more precision, it's far away and really not immediate to find, but really interesting.

Comment: @Alexander how about such an objective: I want to subclass a NSString because I want to create a special string, which has some special methods to validate its contents. Extending String with those methods is a bad idea -- I don't want to make those methods available to all String instances. Would appreciate your answer

Comment: @rommex Use composition instead of inheritance. Make a new struct that simply contains a string. Then you can make a failable initializer that takes a string, performs validation, and returns a new struct only if the validation passed. That way, anytime you see an instance of YourType, you can be sure that it's valid, and you can never "forget" to validate it by accident

Comment: @Alexander thanks for your quick answer. But your solution is not suitable for me. 1. In composition I lose all the String's functionality, which I should bridge. 2. Validation of my String is done interactively, many times as the String mutates.

Comment: @rommex 1. No, you just have to either write forwarding properties/functions, or access the wrapped string and call methods on it directly (though you have to be careful with that, to not accidentally allow mutability) 2. What's your usecase exactly? Why is the same same string repeatedly mutated?

Comment: @Alexander, 1. That's what I called by bridging, sorry if it was not clear. I lose all properties and functions from original String and have to forward them (what if I need 20-30 of them?). 2. I receive a String from UITextField and have to validate it as the user keeps typing.

Comment: @rommex So you would forward your changes to the struct, and have it internally update its data, and throw an error or return nil if validation fails. That validating wrapper can then expose a read-only view to the string it wraps, so that you can use it like any old string, without risk to invalidating its internal state