# Do instance references really work in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, reference, nsdictionary, swift-playground

I wrote the Objective-C code first

```
NSMutableString *aStrValue = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Hello"];
NSMutableDictionary *aMutDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[aMutDict setObject:aStrValue forKey:@"name"];

NSLog(@"Before %@",aMutDict);
[aStrValue appendString:@" World"];
NSLog(@"After %@",aMutDict);
```

I got the output as follows

```
2015-09-17 14:27:21.052 ShareIt[4946:129853] Before {
    name = Hello;
}
2015-09-17 14:27:21.057 ShareIt[4946:129853] After {
    name = "Hello World";
}
```

Means when I append a string to a Mutable string which is actually referred into a MutableDictionary, the change is getting reflected in Dictionary too..

But then I tried something same in Swift

```
var stringValue:String?
stringValue = "Hello"

var dict:Dictionary = ["name":stringValue!]
println(dict)
stringValue! += " World"
stringValue!.extend(" !!!!")
println(dict)
```

I seen the output in playground like this
[image]

**My Questions are**

- Why the value that changed is not reflecting in a data structure like
  Dictionary.
- Does in Swift adding any key value really keeps the value or its
  reference, if it's keeping the reference like objective-C then here what is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Reference type

The different behaviours depends on the fact that in the Objective-C code you use `NSMutableString` that is a `class`.
This means that `aMutDict` and `aStrValue` are **references to the same object** of type `NSMutableString`. So the changes you apply using `aStrValue` are visibile by `aMutDict`.

### Value type

On the other hand in Swift you are using the `String` `struct`. This is a **value type**. This means that when you copy the value from one variable to another, the change you do using the first variable are not visible to the second one.

The following example clearly describes the `value type` behaviour:

```
var word0 = "Hello"
var word1 = word0

word0 += " world" // this will NOT impact word1

word0 // "Hello world"
word1 // "Hello"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @user2864740: How? appzYourLife's answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: @user2864740: Both examples (`Objective-C` and `Swift`) are in the **mutable context**. Infact the OP uses `NSMutableString`, `NSMutableDictionary`, `var String` and  `var Dictionary` (all `mutables`). The real difference here is that `NSMutableString` is an object (**reference type**) while `String` is a struct (**value type**). So here we are talking about `reference types` and `value types`, **not mutability**.

Comment: @appzYourLife The `+` operator does not mutate the String but rather returns a new value; in any context. The resulting assignment (to a variable) and following `extend` are thus independent of any value stored in the dictionary, in any context. To make it a question of value type vs reference type (and not just immutability of operations) would require an actual operation that attempted to modify the original object, and then explain the behavior therein.

Comment: One more thing – in ObjC, only `NSMutableString` is passed as reference type, on the other hand `NSString` behaves like a value type. That's because of thing known as [string interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) – Matt told me [here](http://nshipster.com/equality/)

Comment: @PavelSmejkal: you are right. I replaced `NSString` with `NSMutableString` in the first paragraph of my answer. Thank you!

Comment: @user2864740: I am afraid you are wrong. Look at this line in the OP `stringValue! += " World"`. This instruction obviously **modify** the content of `stringValue`. But since `stringValue` is a `value type` the change is not reflected inside the `Dictionary` because **it has a copy**. So we are talking about `reference type` and `value type`. **Not mutabilty/immutability**.

Comment: @appzYourLife `+=` does not modify the original string any more than it modifies an integer. It is merely a compound assignment - [as shown in this code](http://swiftstub.com/254516565/?v=gm). *The 'example of the difference' code shown would have worked the way it does on any operations that did not mutate the original type.*

Comment: @appzYourLife Personally I think the Swift documentation is hogwash as written with too sloppy a mixture of mutability/immutability of *objects* (values) and *bindings* (names which represent values) - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221786/are-swift-mutable-strings-really-mutable-or-are-they-just-like-java-strings

Comment: @appzYourLife That being said, if you can show me any example of *actually* mutating a *string value* as opposed to a *binding*, I would be most interested to see it.

Comment: @user2864740 Very good point I understand what you mean but please let's examine togheter some facts. **1)** The Swift `copy on write` technique does not seem applied looking at the result of `unsafeAddressOf` here http://swiftstub.com/324640401/?v=gm Why? **2)** `unsafeAddressOf` accepts as param `AnyObject`, why does `String` (a `struct`) conform to AnyObject? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403542/swift-string-doesnt-conform-to-anyobject **3)** With mechanisms of abstractions like `copy on write` (and maybe others) is it safe and reliable for us considering memory addresses of structs?

Comment: @user2864740: I mean, when I write `word0 += " world"` I can consider `word0` a `struct`, `mutable` and `value type`. At low level I understand that `word0` is still a pointer and that the next line `word0` does point to a different memory location but these are details we should not care about here (IMHO). As I don't care that `let word0 = "hello"; let word1 = word` actually creates 2 `pointers` to the **same memory location**. Because conceptually `word0` and `word1` are simply 2 independent value types. And if I treat them like that Swift will take care of the rest.

Comment: @user2864740: But seriously, I see your point. I could be wrong and I would like to know what you think about.

Comment: @user2864740: I asked a specific question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638879/swift-strings-and-memory-addresses

Comment: @appzYourLife Ahh, [me too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637688/is-it-possible-to-mutate-a-string-in-swift-such-that-it-can-be-proven-to-modify) (from a different angle). Very interesting learning new stuff - ie. I thought the address would have been pinned without an in-between operations.

Comment: Yes, thanks to this "thread" I discovered a few new thing today :D

Answer (score 4):

Strings in Swift (copy by value) are completely different than string in Objective C (copy by reference).

From Apple' Swift documentation:

> Strings Are Value Types
>
> Swift’s String type is a value type. If you create a new String value,
>   that String value is copied when it is passed to a function or method,
>   or when it is assigned to a constant or variable. In each case, a new
>   copy of the existing String value is created, and the new copy is
>   passed or assigned, not the original version. Value types are
>   described in Structures and Enumerations Are Value Types.
>
> Swift’s copy-by-default String behavior ensures that when a function
>   or method passes you a String value, it is clear that you own that
>   exact String value, regardless of where it came from. You can be
>   confident that the string you are passed will not be modified unless
>   you modify it yourself.
>
> Behind the scenes, Swift’s compiler optimizes string usage so that
>   actual copying takes place only when absolutely necessary. This means
>   you always get great performance when working with strings as value
>   types.

Answer (score 2):

In swift, String is a Struct.
Structs are not reference types in Swift, thus it's copied when you setting it to a dictionary.

Comment: @user2864740: [Strings in Swift are structs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112081/is-string-type-a-class-or-a-struct-or-something-else), _not_ reference types.

Comment: @user2864740: Then please provide an answer. So far you're only disagreeing with people and don't provide any useful data.

Comment: @user2864740 This answer says what the problem is in couple words and it's right, thanks