# Swift struct initialization, making another struct like String

Tags: swift, xcode, struct, initialization

on Swift `String` is a **struct** and you could just initialize it using

```
var someString:String = "Hello"
```

how would I make another Struct initializable like String?

for example

```
struct StringV2 {
    init()
}

class SomeClass {
    let someStringV2:StringV2 = "Hello"
}
```

Since that's how `String`'s code looks like.

Comment: I think this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112081/is-string-type-a-class-or-a-struct-or-something-else

Comment: For Swift 2 you'll find an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27713005/1187415.

Comment: We don't know what your intentions are, but writing up a new string type is a pretty niche thing that pretty much never comes up. Most likely what you're trying to achieve can be more easily, and better, done using an extension.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov yep I know of extensions but right now I'm just trying to make a new string type. for learning purposes :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is (in my opinion) neat part of the language. Yes, this is possible, thanks to the [`ExpressibleByStringLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/expressiblebystringliteral) protocol.

Unfortunately, there is some complexity to it. [`ExpressibleByStringLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/expressiblebystringliteral) inherits from [`ExpressibleByExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/expressiblebyextendedgraphemeclusterliteral), which itself inherits from [`ExpressibleByUnicodeScalarLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/expressiblebyunicodescalarliteral). Thus, to conform to the first, you must conform to the other 2 above it.

This makes it possible for your struct or class to be initialized from:

- A `UnicodeScalarLiteralType` (such as a `UnicodeScalar`, which is a single Unicode code point, e.g. `"A"`)
- An `ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType` (such as a `Character`, which is a collection of `UnicodeScalar`s, such as `""`)
- A `StringLiteralType` (such as `String`, which is a collection of `Characters`, such as `"This is a string"`)

Here's an example implementation that just sets a `String` member variable:

```
struct StringV2: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    let s: String

    init(unicodeScalarLiteral: UnicodeScalar) {
        s = String(unicodeScalarLiteral)
    }

    init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral: Character) {
        s = String(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral)
    }

    init(stringLiteral: String) {
        s = stringLiteral
    }
}

let s1: StringV2 = "This is a string" // String
print(s1.s)

let s2: StringV2 = "A" // Unicode scalar
print(s2.s)

let s3: StringV2 = "" // Extended grapheme cluster
print(s3.s)
```

Comment: I guess whether you give "A" or "", it will go to `init(stringLiteral: StringLiteralType)` only

Comment: You can also omit all the type aliases and define `init(stringLiteral: String)` etc.

Comment: @MartinR Oh yeah, it'll just infer the associated types. Nifty.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Interesting observation. And casting doesn't make it work either. What's up with that?

Comment: Probably thats a Character and you have to make that with conforming the `ExpressibleByExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteral`

Comment: better to use extensions here

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari It depends on what the OP's intent is. It's not yet clear

Comment: I know for most cases it's better to use @RajanMaheshwari. my intentions for this was just to grasp more on using Structs as `String`'s use of its **init** was way different from other Structs which used something like `SomeStruct(value: someValue)`

Comment: How is `String`'s use of `init()` any different?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov by that I mean you can just use `var someString:String = "some value"` while on some structs you should use `var someCGPoint:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)`. get what I mean?

Comment: Apart from the special literal syntax that exists for String, it's just calling a constructor under the hood. There's no real difference